# ModelBuilder Iteration - Don't want to re-iterate through certain processes?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, table, iterator

I can't seem to figure out how to not re-iterate through the beginning part of my model whereby I import a table from excel into a dbf and join it to the feature classes being iterated. I am copying over data from the imported table by carrying out a join and then just field calc-ing the joined fields over to the appropriate standard fields. The model works but with each iteration it re-imports the excel table, causing the whole process to take longer than needed.

How do I set up the model so that it only imports the excel table once?

Also, is there an easier way to import data from excel and populate into the appropriate fields than the way I'm doing it?

I've attached a screen shot below:[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ModelBuilder is a bit strange when it comes to iterations (For example only one iterator per model).

To solve your problem you can integrate a model into another. You can then call the submodel with your table import into the original model and it should not be iterated.
Some info here: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/modelbuilder/integrating-model-within-a-model.htm

A second option might be (did not test, but could work) is to load your table into a stand-alone variable: http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisengine/java/gp_toolref/automating_your_work_with_models/working_with_variables.htm

Comment: Thanks Matte, integrating the iteration and field calcs into another model within seemed to do the trick.